# Get file size and save it to a variable in MB[BATCH]

Tags: file, batch-file, size

I have a file called Update.zip and It's size is 50.25MB.
And I also have this command:

```
for %%A in (Update) do set Size=%%~zA
echo %Size% MB
pause>nul
```

And I get output like this: 50250.
I want the batch file to output the file size in MB so the output should look like this:

```
50.25 MB
```

Anybody?

Comment: Try `echo %Size: =.% MB` if does not matter that 50250 `KiB` = cca 49.07 `MiB` (as `K` and `M` are customary prefixes for accurate `Ki` and `Mi`, respectively). Cf. [Binary prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)

Comment: It's still get the same output

Comment: You did ask for `50 250` with a _space_ inside... See answer by @npocmaka

Comment: oh.. I'm sorry.. I did so because it is easier to read xD

Answer (score 2):

*Errare humanum est*.

For better understanding, here is an integrated script (definitive  version, explanations in code `rem` comments); pay your attention to the `:ConvToMi` subroutine:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
    call :main
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:ConvToMi
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::: 
::: %1 = a number to process, should be less than 2^31
::: %2 = (optional) conversion base (1024 or 1000); 1024 if omitted
::: 
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    rem establish conversion base and units of measurement
set /A "kibi=10000%~2%%10000"
if %kibi% equ 0 set /A "kibi=1024"
set /A "mibi=kibi*kibi"
    rem suffix
if %kibi% equ 1024 ( set "sfx=iB") else ( set "sfx=B ")

    rem  SizeB in bytes
set /A "SizeB=%~1" 2>NUL
if not %errorlevel% EQU 0 set "SizeB=%~1"

    rem SizeK in kilobytes
set /a "SizeK=SizeB/kibi"
set /a "SizeKR=SizeB%%kibi"

    rem reverse calculation for correctness check 
set /a "BackK=kibi*SizeK+SizeKR"
if "%BackK%"=="%SizeB%" (set "failS= ") else (set "failS=f")

    rem simple proportion from 1024ths to thousandths
set /a "SizeKR=(SizeKR*1000)/kibi"
    rem three digits following decimal point 
set "SizeKR=000%SizeKR%"
set "SizeKR=%SizeKR:~-3%"

set "SizeK3=%SizeK%.%SizeKR%"

    rem SizeM in megabytes
set /a "SizeM=SizeB/mibi"
set /a "SizeMR=SizeB%%mibi"

    rem simple proportion to millionths
    rem divided to two sequenced steps as there is 2^31-1 limit
set /a "SizeMR=(SizeMR*1000)/kibi"
set /a "SizeMR=(SizeMR*1000)/kibi"

    rem six digits following decimal point
set "SizeMR=000000%SizeMR%"
set "SizeMR=%SizeMR:~-6%"

set "SizeM6=%SizeM%.%SizeMR%"

    rem round MB to 3 ciphers ("supermarket" round: 5 up)
set /A "SizeM3=((500+(1%SizeMR%%%1000)%%1000)/1000)+(1%SizeMR:~0,3%%%1000)"
    rem treat a carry if any comes on
if  %SizeM3% gtr 999 set /A "SizeM+=1"
    rem three digits following decimal point  
set "SizeM3=000%SizeM3%"
set "SizeM3=%SizeM3:~-3%"

set "SizeM3=%SizeM%.%SizeM3%"

echo %failS% %kibi%: %SizeB% B  =%SizeK3% K%sfx%  =%SizeM6% M%sfx%  ~%SizeM3% M%sfx%

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:main
    rem output verified for some values with calc.exe
set "testStr=13709312 1000 999999 999999999"
    rem 2^27 neighbourhood
set "testStr=%testStr% 134217724 134217728 134217732"
    rem semifinal value 2147483647==2^31-1 limit of 'set /A' command 
    rem final value 2147483648==2^31 exceeds limit, output defective
    rem set /A "x=2147483648"
    rem                raises  errorlevel=1073750992 with next message:  
    rem Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.
set "testStr=%testStr% 2147483647 2147483648"
    rem set "testStr=2147483647 2147483648"
    rem set "testStr=2147483647"

for %%A in ( %testStr% ) do ( 
  call :ConvToMi %%A  1000
  call :ConvToMi %%A 
  echo(
)
echo done
goto :eof
```

**Output**:

```
==>28526273.bat
  1000: 13709312 B  =13709.312 KB   =13.709312 MB   ~13.709 MB
  1024: 13709312 B  =13388.000 KiB  =13.074218 MiB  ~13.074 MiB

  1000: 1000 B  =1.000 KB   =0.001000 MB   ~0.001 MB
  1024: 1000 B  =0.976 KiB  =0.000953 MiB  ~0.001 MiB

  1000: 999999 B  =999.999 KB   =0.999999 MB   ~1.000 MB
  1024: 999999 B  =976.561 KiB  =0.953672 MiB  ~0.954 MiB

  1000: 999999999 B  =999999.999 KB   =999.999999 MB   ~1000.000 MB
  1024: 999999999 B  =976562.499 KiB  =953.674315 MiB  ~953.674 MiB

  1000: 134217724 B  =134217.724 KB   =134.217724 MB   ~134.218 MB
  1024: 134217724 B  =131071.996 KiB  =127.999996 MiB  ~128.000 MiB

  1000: 134217728 B  =134217.728 KB   =134.217728 MB   ~134.218 MB
  1024: 134217728 B  =131072.000 KiB  =128.000000 MiB  ~128.000 MiB

  1000: 134217732 B  =134217.732 KB   =134.217732 MB   ~134.218 MB
  1024: 134217732 B  =131072.003 KiB  =128.000002 MiB  ~128.000 MiB

  1000: 2147483647 B  =2147483.647 KB   =2147.483647 MB   ~2147.484 MB
  1024: 2147483647 B  =2097151.999 KiB  =2047.999999 MiB  ~2048.000 MiB

f 1000: 2147483648 B  =2147483.647 KB   =2147.483647 MB   ~2147.484 MB
f 1024: 2147483648 B  =2097151.999 KiB  =2047.999999 MiB  ~2048.000 MiB

done
==>
```

However, [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) belongs to [npocmaka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28528980/3439404)...

Answer (score 0):

for more precise calculation you can use 1024

```
for %%A in (Update) do set SizeK=%%~zA

set /a SizeM=SizeK/1000
set /a SizeMR=SizeK%%1000
set Size=SizeM.SizeMR
echo %Size% MB
pause>nul
```

Comment: Third attempt, yours and mine as well... For example `1090 B` results erroneously to `1.9 MB`, should be `1.090 KB`, see my _stolen_ answer. And (btw) filename extension missing in `for ...`